# Does $ Tx=\left( T_1x_1, T_2x_2, \cdots \right) $ define an element of $ L( \oplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n , \oplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n ) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Given Hilbert spaces $ H_1, H_2, \cdots $ with inner products $ \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2, \cdots $ and norms $ \|\cdot\|_1, \|\cdot\|_2, \cdots, $ respectively, consider
$$ \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\left\{ \underline{x}=(x_1, x_2, \cdots )\in \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\|_n^2<\infty  \right\}. $$
Given $ T_n\in L(H_n,H_n) $ for $ n=1,2,\cdots , $ define for each $ \underline{x}\in \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n $
$$ T\underline{x}=\left( T_1x_1, T_2x_2, \cdots \right). $$
Does $ T $ always define an element of $ L\big(  \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n , \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n \big) $? I want to prove it or give a counterexample. I think the answer to the question is no, but I need help to come up with a counterexample. Anyone?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether $T$ linear or bounded linear?

Comment: @Bernard Wojcik. Bounded linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no I think. Take $H_i = \mathbb{R}$ and $T_i$ multiplication with $i$. Each $T_i$ is bounded but $T$ is not bounded if you look norm 1 vectors in $H$ of the form $(0,...0,1,0,...)$

Answer (score 3):

To get a positive result, you need that $K:= \sup_{\mathbb N} \lVert T_n \rVert  < \infty$. Then
$$
 \lVert Tx \rVert ^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lVert T_i x_i \rVert ^2 \leq K^2 \lVert x \rVert^2.
$$